# How to debug at viewDidDisappear or dealloc?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging

I want debugger to stop at viewDidDisappear or dealloc in root view controller when I quit application.
But debugger does not go to the break point.
How can I make debugger stop at break point or print NSLog() statement?

Comment: The debugger should stop there. If it doesn't, those functions might not be called in the first place.

Comment: How do you quit app? I quit my app by clicking stop button in toolbar. It never stops at break point of dealloc.

Comment: You usually don't quit an app yourself. You can do it by going to the iPhones home screen, double tap the home button and quit your app there, but again, you usually don't. Which dealloc function do you observe? The one in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I want to debug dealloc in main view controller. When I quit my app in Xcode, i click stop button in toolbar. How do you quit your app in Xcode? I want to know how you can step into dealloc in main view. In my case, I can not step into dealloc. My app just quit.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, your problem is that specifically the `MainViewControllers` `dealloc` doesn't get called. Truth is, that it will be called but only in certain cases. If you terminate your app with xCode it, well, get's terminated, so it won't call `dealloc`. If you, on the other hand, just press the home button, with iOS4 and above, your app will continue running in the background, so no dealloc either. `Dealloc` however will be called if a) you force quit your app via the iPhones 'task manager' (double press the home button) or b) if the OS decides to quit your 'cause it needs it's memory.

Since you most likely don't just want to release something in `dealloc` (the app will be gone afterwards anyway), I suspect that you want to perform certain actions before the user leaves your app. To do that, you should use [`applicationDidEnterBackground`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) or [`applicationWillTerminate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a)

Comment: Even though I double press the home button of simulator, dealloc is not called, I want to make sure that everything is released just before app is terminated. That is my purpose of debugging dealloc. There semms no way to step into dealloc.

Comment: You read what I am saying, don't you? You don't need to release the stuff, it goes away when your app terminates anyway. For everything else, use applicationWillTerminate, just as I wrote...

Comment: I don't understand why all exmaple programs do release in dealloc.